# Java ArrayList clear() method

Tags: java, arraylist

I can't really understand the code below. 
The clear method removes all elements assigned to "al" right? Then the ArrayList al receives the value of string Str2 and alal receives the value of Str3.

So how on earth the output is as below if alal is assigned only with Str3? Could someone kindly explain? Many thanks

**OUTPUT:**

[String 2]

[[String 2], String 3]

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String Str1 = "String 1";
    String Str2 = "String 2";
    String Str3 = "String 3";


    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList alal = new ArrayList();


    al.add(Str1);
    alal.add(al);

    al.clear();

    al.add(Str2);
    alal.add(Str3);

    System.out.println(al);
    System.out.println(alal);
}
```

Comment: alal has reference of al

Comment: You added `al` to `alal` ... why would you think it wouldn't still be there?

Comment: My guess would be that when adding it makes a deep copy of the AL object. I don't believe it is just making a reference to the object.

Comment: @DerekParker That would be completely incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using raw `ArrayList`, thus you can store any kind of `Object` in your lists. Note that you're storing `al` inside `alal`, which means storing the reference of `al` into `alal`, not the values from `al` into `alal`.

More in depth explanation:

```
al.add(Str1); //al -> [String 1]
alal.add(al); //alal -> [ [String 1] ]

al.clear(); //al -> []   ,   alal -> [ [] ]
al.add(Str2); // al -> [String 2] , alal -> [ [String 2] ]
alal.add(Str3); //alal -> [ [String 2], String 3]

System.out.println(al);
System.out.println(alal);
```

Some advices from your given code:

- Use better names for your variables. `al` and `alal` may look *good* for a basic example, but it would be better providing names that help to the code readability.
- If you want to prevent you or another programmer to store *anything* in an `ArraList` (or in another `Collection`), use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). This mean, declare the variable like `ArrayList<String> alal` so now the compiler will check that you can add `String` values only.
- If you wanted to pass the elements from `al` to `alal`, use [`ArrayList#addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) method.
- In this case, it would be better declaring the variables as `List` instead to `ArrayList`. It is better to get used to [program to an interface rather than a direct class implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197):

Comment: Many thanks @Luiggi Mendoza, now I understood. When I use the clear() it removes the elements but not the reference given to it. Thanks all.

Comment: this code is from a Java exam and I guess it was designed to make students confused... hence the variable names...

Comment: put this way... this is only the first question of the exam and there are more 13 to follow.....LOL

Answer (score 0):

because `alal` has reference of `al`

Any change made to `al` reference will reflect in `alal`

Answer (score 0):

You never cleared alal, so it still contains al when you add Str3.

Comment: Yes, I realized my mistake just seconds after I posted and fixed it. Wow, people are very quick to jump on typos here XD

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `alal.add(al);`, you are not copying anything from `al` into `alal`, you are actually making the first element of `alal` be `al` (you are storing a list into a list, which is allowed). When you clear `al`, you remove every element from it, but do not create a new list (that would no longer be in `alal`.
When you go to print `alal`, you are printing every element in it. The first element is the list `al`, which prints as `[String 2]` (and then the `String 3`).

Answer (score 0):

First, in your code, you are declaring 3 String variables (Str1, Str2 and Str3) and 2 ArrayList (al and alal).

Now, you are adding the element Str1 to your list al with:

```
al.add(Str1); //Here your variable al has the value ["String1"]
```

And when you assign

```
alal.add(al); // Now your variable alal has the value [["String1"]]
```

and when you add the new element to your variable alal the result is

```
alal.add(Str3); // Now you are adding the string to your array, and the result is `[["String1"],"String 3"]`
```

If you need remove the result before to assignee a new result you need do a `.clear` to your alal variable only to contains a string array and not arrays of string.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider what happens line by line:

**1.**

```
al.add(Str1);
```

`al` now contains the String "String 1" so it looks like: ["String 1"]

**2.**

```
alal.add(al);
```

`alal` now contains `al` (`al` currently is ["String 1"]). So, `alal` looks like: [["String 1"]]

**3.**

```
al.clear();
```

Since the content of `al` is cleared, it now looks like: []
But `alal` also has a reference to `al` so `alal` will look like: [[]]

**4.**

```
al.add(Str2);
```

`al` will now look like: ["String 2"]
As we know, `alal` also has a reference to `al` so `alal` will look like: [["String 2"]]

**5.**

```
alal.add(Str3);
```

Finally, we add "String 3" to `alal` (which is currrently [["String 2"]]), so it becomes: [["String 2"], "String 3"]

**Finally**

Now `al` is ["String 2"] and, `alal` is [["String 2"], "String 3"]